# null=True,blank=True but still error may not be null is raised everytime during post

Tags: django

my model:

```
    Assets(modes.Model):
      assset_code=models.CharField(max_length=12,null=True,blank=True)
```

In my serializers.py:

```
 asset_code=serializers.CharField(max_length=12,allow_blank=True,required=False)
```

When I post data, it still says this field may not be null. It lets me pass only if I put data.

While I am at it, whats the correct way to make JSONField() optional in serializers too?

Comment: Is it django or django-rest framework?

Comment: Sharing your error trackback will be helpful.

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali: yes it is DRF

Comment: @misraX there is no error traceback...just {"detail": "This field may not be null"}. If enter data to it, there is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using `null=True` in a String field and if you need to set `null=True` it's only under the bellow exception and for more about  `null` check django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#null)

> **Django Documentation**:
>
> One exception is when a CharField has both unique=True and blank=True
>   set. In this situation, null=True is required to avoid unique
>   constraint violations when saving multiple objects with blank values.

Setting `blank=True` (django model and forms), `allow_blank=True` (DRF) is enough for django forms, django admin and Django REST Framework to understand that this field is not required, and the field value will be saved as an empty string in your Database.

The same goes for `null` in Django REST Framework avoid using `allow_null=True`, check [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield)

> **Django REST Framework Documentation**:
>
> its usage is discouraged in favor of allow_blank. It is valid to set
>   both allow_blank=True and allow_null=True, but doing so means that
>   there will be two differing types of empty value permissible for
>   string representations, which can lead to data inconsistencies and
>   subtle application bugs.

So your `asset_code` arguments and any future string field that follow the same scenario, `blank=True` is enough for django models, and `allow_blank=True` is enough for DRF.

```
# models.py
assset_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)

# serializer.py
assset_code = serializers.CharField(max_length=12, allow_blank=True)
```

Comment: how is that helping?.
question was 
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'container_field': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be null.', code='null')]}

despite having set 'allow_null": True, 'allow_blank':True , and obviously the models

Infact, if I dont send anything my db will set it to NULL because its legacy database, and I set the command to DEFALT NULL